# Изменение размера фото атрибута товара

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Не могу изменить размер фото в атрибутах товара
Пробовал менять через CSS, но если менять через него, то  качество картинки ухудшается и делать это не имеет смысла. Может быть в настройках WP или WooCommerce, или в настройках темы (Использую тему flatsome). Заранее спасибо!
[image: Фото товара]

Comment: Как правило это делается в плагине, которым ты это реализовал.

Comment: @SeVlad, я смотрел в Woocommerce, но там нет этого

Comment: Да, WC не выводит картинки вариаций для их выбора. Это делает какой-то другой плагин. Коих десятки.